# How do we know we're maximizing the Lagrangian objective function in PCA?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, principal-component-analysis

In Principal Component Analysis, we start with $m$ observations $x_1,\dots,x_m$, each of which is an $n$-dimensional vector. Assume we have centered the data; that is, we have subtracted the variable means from each observation. To project each observation into a $1$-dimensional subspace while maximizing sample variance, we want to compute a unit length basis vector, call it $v$. So we get the constrained problem

$$
\mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_{v}\,\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left\lVert\langle x_i,v\rangle v\right\rVert
$$

$$
\text{subject to }v^Tv=1
$$

After some computations, this becomes

$$
\mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_{v}\,\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}v^TCv
$$

$$
\text{subject to }v^Tv=1
$$

where $C$ is the covariance matrix of the data. Then the Lagrangian objective function is

$$
\mathcal{L}(v,\lambda)=v^TCv-\lambda(v^Tv-1)
$$

If we start taking partial derivatives of $\mathcal{L}$, setting these to zero, etc, how do we know that we are maximizing $\mathcal{L}$? Do we need to check that the Hessian is negative definite? Even then, I think that only guarantees a local maximum?

Answer (score 1):

Define $K:=\frac{C+C^T}{2}-\lambda I$. Note that $\mathcal{L}=v^T Kv+\lambda$ is a quadratic, so if $K$ is definite the local turning point, which solves $Kv=0$ from the first derivative of $\mathcal{L}$, is also a global extremum. I've written the coefficient as a symmetric real matrix so it's diagonalisable, viz. $\mathcal{L}=\sum_i K_{ii}v_i^2+\lambda$. In our choice of basis $Kv=0$ simplifies to $K_{ii}\ne 0\implies v_i=0$. This maximises $\mathcal{L}$ provided each of the eigenvalues $K_{ii}$ is at most $0$. Indeed, the solution is for $\lambda$ to be the largest eigenvalue of $\frac{C+C^T}{2}$, with $v$ a unit eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$; then $K$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue, but no positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you. Why is the local turning point a global extremum if $K$ is definite? Why does diagonalisability give an obvious result? Which vector space?

Comment: @waynemystir Hopefully my edit makes it clearer.

Comment: I'm confused. What is $V$ or $V_i$? A vector and component? Is $K$ the coefficient? So you diagonalised $K$ and rewrote $\mathcal{L}$ relative to this change of basis? Why does the stationary point solve $KV=0$?

Comment: @waynemystir I hope my latest edit is even clearer. $v_i$ is indeed a component of $v$.

Comment: Why is the solution for $\lambda$ to be the largest eigenvalue of $\frac{C+C^T}{2}$? Taking partials, I see $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. But why does it need to be the largest? The equation $\mathcal{L}(v,\lambda)=v^TCv-\lambda(v^Tv-1)=v^TCv=v^T\lambda v=\lambda$ only tells us that $\mathcal{L}$ attains the eigenvalue $\lambda$. This equation doesn't reveal that it's the largest one.

Comment: @waynemystir Because we need $v$ to be an eigenvalue-$0$ eigenvector of $K$, which has no positive eigenvalues.

Comment: And why does $K$ have no positive eigenvalues? I thought that that was what we are trying to prove, @J.G. .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86634/discussion-between-j-g-and-waynemystir).

Comment: Happy to, thank you.